# How to add a footer button to my recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, footer

I want to add a footer to my recycler view. I have attached the custom adapter code below. How can I do this? I want the button to fill the recycler view with new items. I can do the button functioning on my own. I'm only facing the problem adding the footer.

I want something like the image attached below:

[image]

```
 package com.example.myapplication.Adapter;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import com.example.myapplication.Interface.ItemClickListener;
    import com.example.myapplication.Model.RSSObject;
    import com.example.myapplication.R;

    class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{
        public TextView textTitle,txtDate,textContent;
        private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;


    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPubDate);
        textContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textContent);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView, ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }
}

    public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder> {
        private RSSObject.RssObject rssObject;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public FeedAdapter(RSSObject.RssObject rssObject, Context mContext) {
        this.rssObject = rssObject;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        layoutInflater = layoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

         
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);

       return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String url = rssObject.getItems().get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getLink();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                v.getContext().startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        String title = rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle();
        title = title.replace("&amp;","");
        holder.textTitle.setText(title);
        String description = rssObject.getItems().get(position).getDescription();
        description = android.text.Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
        holder.textContent.setText(description);
        holder.txtDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return rssObject.items.size();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to add a footer, you need to specify it as another type of view.
In your adapter code you should add logic for creation of another holder for the footer.
Please see the following Kotlin example:

```
const val REGULAR_VIEW_TYPE = 0
const val FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE = 1  

class FooterExampleAdapter(
    private val data: List<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
    when (viewType) { // Use 'when' to create the correct holder for any position
        REGULAR_VIEW_TYPE -> RegularViewHolder(parent.inflateView(R.layout.regular_layout))
        FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE -> FooterViewHolder(parent.inflateView(R.layout.footer_layout))
    }

// Handle binding by checking holder type
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is RegularViewHolder) holder.bind(data[position])
    else if (holder is FooterViewHolder) holder.bind()
}

override fun getItemCount() = data.size + 1 // We need the extra 1 for the footer to be counted

// Here is where we specify which view type should be presented at position
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) =
    if (position == data.size) FOOTER_VIEW_TYPE else REGULAR_VIEW_TYPE
}


class RegularViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    fun bind(string: String) {}
}  


class FooterViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    fun bind() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:
If you want a fixed view put under RecyclerView in your xml file a Relative Layout (or orher) with the button inside
Or if you want the button as an element of the list you should add a view with the button ad the last position of your view

Comment: Yeah I want the button as the last element of the recycler view ...but i don't know how to do that..please can you explain in more detail...